# && (logical and) and || (logical or) operators in Logback configuration (if statement)

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

I am having trouble with multiples condition in IF statement into logback-spring.xml configuration file.

I have a condition for example `condition='isDefined("SOME_PROP_1")'` and another one `condition='isDefined("SOME_PROP_2")'`.

So as you can all asume by now I want to use those two condition in ONE if statement like this:

```
<if condition='isDefined("SOME_PROP_1") && isDefined("SOME_PROP_2")'>
   ...
</if>
```

OR

```
<if condition='isDefined("SOME_PROP_1") || isDefined("SOME_PROP_2")'>
   ...
</if>
```

Now the ***logical or*** works but the ***logical and*** does not because the & symbol is preserved. Does someone is aware how the ***logical and*** operator looks like in logback configuration ?

Comment: Change your `&&` to `&amp;&amp;` Try with this and if you can please give me a feedback

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: Yes `&amp` followed by `;` as you edited it does the job ! Good stuff @Gatusko. Silly me not having a thought to just escape the symbol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well you need to change your && to `&amp;&amp;`
Because:

> In HTML, the ampersand character (“&”) declares the beginning of an
>   entity reference (a special character). If you want one to appear in
>   text on a web page you should use the encoded named entity `&amp;`

Hope it helped you